# Simplifying $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}+1} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{11}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I realize that is a basic math problem, but I am still having problems with it.

The expression $$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}+1} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{11}$$ equals one of the following:

- $2\sqrt{3}-1$
- $\dfrac{6}{11}$
- $4\sqrt{3}$
- $12$

How do I simplify this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint:

First Rationalize the denominator of first term by multiplying numerator and denominator with denominator's conjugate and then use 
$$(a+b)(a-b)=a^2-b^2$$

> $$\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}+1} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{11}=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2\sqrt{3}+1}\cdot\frac{2\sqrt{3}-1}{2\sqrt{3}-1} + \frac{\sqrt{3}}{11}=\frac{6-\sqrt3}{(2\sqrt3)^2-1}+ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{11}=\frac{6-\sqrt3}{11}+ \frac{\sqrt{3}}{11}$$

Comment: It's advisable to avoid spoon feeding and leave at something for the OP:)

Answer (score 2):

$$\begin{align}\frac{\sqrt3}{2\sqrt3+1}+\frac{\sqrt3}{11}&=\frac{\sqrt3(2\sqrt3-1)}{(2\sqrt3+1)(2\sqrt3-1)}+\frac{\sqrt3}{11}\\&=\frac{6-\sqrt3}{11}+\frac{\sqrt3}{11}\\&=\frac{6}{11}\end{align}$$